# runtime error inputstream cannot be null

Tags: java, android

i have this runtime error in my logcat:

```
05-11 06:24:23.672: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(327): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    Unable to create application net.osmand.activities.OsmandApplication:
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream cannot be null
```

...

after debugin i found the exception comme how???
 in  this methode :

```
private BaseOsmandRender loadRenderer(String name, Set<String> loadedRenderers) throws IOException, SAXException {
        InputStream is = null;
        if(externalRenderers.containsKey(name)){
            is = new FileInputStream(externalRenderers.get(name));
        } else if(internalRenderers.containsKey(name)){
            is = OsmandRenderingRulesParser.class.getResourceAsStream(internalRenderers.get(name));
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not found " + name); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
        BaseOsmandRender b = new BaseOsmandRender();
        b.init(is);
        loadedRenderers.add(name);
        List<BaseOsmandRender> dependencies = new ArrayList<BaseOsmandRender>();
        for (String s : b.getDepends()) {
            if (loadedRenderers.contains(s)) {
```

the "is" varible is always  null

any help please

Comment: **is** is initialized in two flows... which one is it following the new FileInputStream, or the OsmandRenderingRulesParser flow?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, `getResourceAsStream` returns `null` if it cannot find the resource.  I suspect that's the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are some crazy restrictions for files in application resources.
If you trying to load resources, try to make *.mp3 extension for them. Its magic.